# React js calling setState twice when invoked from componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Got a weird unexpected behavior in react.
I created a parent component with a method to register (push to a state-array) child elements, which the child element will invoke on componentDidMount. for some reason each element is registered twice because each call invokes setState twice on the parent component.

Notes:

- I have disabled the parent-component rendering by overriding shouldComponentUpdate, and this scenario still happens.
- I have checked that none of the registered elements get unmounted.
- I want to avoid checks for multiple registrations, and to control it with the react life-cycle methods.

The registration method:

```
register_field = (field_to_register) => {
    this.setState((prev_state) => {
        let new_fields = prev_state.fields;
        new_fields.push(field_to_register);
        return {fields: new_fields};
    })
}
```

I tried to debug it using the console debugger, and the second registration iteration happens when App.js invokes render (the first registration iteration happens before).

Comment: you are mutating previous state this will cause side effects.  create a new array from the old one before pushing and returning it.  `prev_state.fields.slice()` or `[ ...prev_state.fields ]`

Comment: Thanks for replying @Deryck, is it possible to not duplicate the entire data-structure? this operation is very expensive in case many registration should happen

Answer (score 0):

Current W.A is to save a property on each child element which will define if the element was registered or not.
I wanted to avoid this kind of solution, but could not find anything usefull.

```
register_field = (field_to_register) => {
this.setState((prev_state) => {
    if(field_to_register.registered){
        return;
    }
    
    field_to_register.registered = true;
    let new_fields = prev_state.fields;
    new_fields.push(field_to_register);
    return {fields: new_fields};
})
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Remove or comment ALL the console.log after your render function in your components.
console.log cause to re-render.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Pascal Nitcheu. Found a similar post abot this subject in https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856. There is no answer for it, just W.A. Figured I could add a dynamic property to the child elements, and use it as a verifier to the registration. But as my notes noted I did not want this kind of solution.